# Text all on one line causes problems with table-cell

Tags: html, css

The text all on one line causes several errors, is not considered the width of the table, and even that of a cell (#tablecell-b, 70px) even with `overflow: hidden`.

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8PxJD/**

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Nowrap will do this to most content.

Comment: I would like all the text on one line, in case of overflow, the text would be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithms for table layout and their width calculations described in the CSS specs are quite complex – so it won’t always work as you want to.

But ins this case, it should be fixable quite easy – by adding `table-layout:fixed` for the table element, see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8PxJD/1/).